# Gamepad loses "focus" on iOS after audio element starts playing

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webrtc, web-audio-api

I have a webrtc game streaming application that I have built. I receive an audio stream from my WebRTC connection and apply the input stream to an audio element. I activate the audio stream from an onclick event. As soon as I do this, I can see that my gamepad no longer updates the input values. The gamepad only updates input state after I tap the screen again. This is on iOS. Is there any way that I can get the browser to regain "focus" as synthetic events don't seem to trigger the gamepad back into focus.

Comment: call focus to whatever element you are listening to for the game pad

Comment: @epascarello gamepad is an object returned by doing a `window.on('gamepadconnected', e => { console.log(e.gamepad)}`  calling focus doesn't work. I also don't know if this is a bug or not? :-(

Comment: I have the exact same issue. This also seems to occur with a non webrtc video (a simple file), when the video is `pause()` and `play()`, as well as when the video loops (I assume it does a `play()` ).
This also seem to occur only on iOS 16 onwards, but I couldn't find anything in the changelog / bug reports in webkit.